# Order the resulting rows based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have to put down the lines that have two distinct fields with value = 0

Let me explain, all records that have `stock_it=0` and `stock_eu=0` must go to the bottom of the results

I have used this solution, however, it is not strictly correct because it puts down even rows that do not have both values = 0

```
$dati = mysql_query("
    SELECT      * 
    FROM        $tb_article
    ORDER BY
        FIELD($tb_art.article_status,'n') DESC, 
        FIELD($tb_art.article_stock_it,'0') ASC, 
        FIELD($tb_art.article_stock_eu,'0') ASC,  
        $tb_art.article_rank
");
```

1. `article_status=n` indicates new products and they have to stay on top!
2. Push to bottom all the article that have stock IT and stock EU = 0 (products not available)
3. In the end, order the rest of the articles according to the rank assigned

Comment: Is this just for a select ? Then edit your question. To sort by rank, you can add a column with some CASE WHEN...

Comment: The complete code is:

`$dati = mysql_query("
 SELECT   * 
 FROM   $tb_article
 ORDER BY
        FIELD($tb_art.article_status,'n') DESC, 
 FIELD($tb_art.article_stock_it,'0') ASC, 
 FIELD($tb_art.article_stock_eu,'0') ASC,  
 $tb_art.article_rank
");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ORDER BY FIELD :
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/913b9/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_article
(
    article_stock_it int,
    article_stock_eu int,
    article_status varchar(11),
    article_rank int
);

INSERT INTO tb_article VALUES
  (1, 1, 'n', 1)
, (0, 1, 'n', 1)
, (0, 0, 'n', 1)
, (1, 1, 'o', 1)
, (1, 1, 'o', 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT      * 
    FROM        tb_article
    ORDER BY
        FIELD(tb_article.article_status,'n') DESC, 
        FIELD(
          IF(tb_article.article_stock_it = 0 AND tb_article.article_stock_eu = 0,'1','0')
          ,'0') DESC,
       tb_article.article_rank
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/913b9/5/0)**:

```
| article_stock_it | article_stock_eu | article_status | article_rank |
|------------------|------------------|----------------|--------------|
|                1 |                1 |              n |            1 |
|                0 |                1 |              n |            1 |
|                0 |                0 |              n |            1 |
|                1 |                1 |              o |            1 |
|                1 |                1 |              o |            2 |
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CASE` statement in `ORDER BY`, like this:

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        $tb_article
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN article_status = 'n' THEN 0
        WHEN article_stock_it = 0 THEN 100000
        WHEN article_stock_eu = 0 THEN 100000
        ELSE article_rank
   END
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's what he asked but i prefer your answer :)

Comment: @JeanDoux thank you :) Any specific reason for preferring my answer?

Comment: I think your solution is faster than with FIELD. But we should do some test to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not give the expected results.

Comment: @ActiveMedia that is fine, thank you giving it a try. Based on my understanding of your question, I have again updated the fiddle, please give it a try as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62b87a/3